# Add items from an SQL Query to Listbox in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

So I have this code that fetches my query.

```
public class Person
{
   public string Ad_Name { get; set; }
}

public string[] getNameAd(string username)
{
   List<String> columnData = new List<String>();
   //var AdNameList = new List<Person>();
   this.OpenConnection();
   string query = "SELECT `Ad_Name` FROM `cpcboos1_textinfo`.`Ad_Info` WHERE     `Ad_Info`.`User` = '" + username + "' LIMIT 0, 1000";
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
   using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
         columnData.Add(reader.GetString(0));
      }
   }
   return columnData.ToList<string>().ToArray();
}
```

I reference this code in my Load function on my Main Form.

```
DBConnect sql = new DBConnect(" *snip* ");
stat_campaign.Items.AddRange(sql.getNameAd(tbx_lgn_user.ToString().Trim()));
```

However all this returns is the text: "(Collection)". That's it. I ran the query on the SQL databse and it returns the correct results. (Just two of them for now.) What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple things going on here, but here are my suggestions :

- Pick one enumerable type to work with and go with it. In this case, you really don't have to  switch between an `array` and a `List<>` - I would have your `getNameAd` method return a `List<string>` so you can bind it to your control. This would also help you organize your code a bit (see below).
- Having said that, why not just set your string list as the `.DataSource` of the listbox control?

  ```
  // get the username    
  var userName = tbx_lgn_user.ToString().Trim();

  // get the query results 
  var listofStrings = sql.getNameAd(userName);

  // bind the list to your ListBox control
  stat_campaign.DataSource = listofStrings;
  ```

Comment: I'll try this and let you know how it works out.   EDIT: This works when the listbox is updated while the program is running. However I need it to fetch the contest of the list box from my server when the Form loads.

Comment: Are you sure you've added this to the `{YourForm}_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` event? Also, make sure you have leave the `DataSource` property of the combo box control set to `(none)`. One other thing possibly, are you sure you're method is returning you a populated list of strings when the form loads?

Comment: It's all set to none. Now it returns a value however it's just the following: "(Collection)". No matter what I do I can't seem to solve this. Do you have a Team Viewer that you could help me with?

Comment: I suppose I could try, although I still feel like there's something obvious that's causing your combo-box to return "(Collection)". Are you sure you don't have that listed under the "Items" property? I mean the actual string "(Collection)".

Comment: I don't have anything that should be returning that. Do you have a Skype or something that I can chat with you on?

Comment: I don't have Skype - could you zip up your project and upload it to DropBox or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try removeing the "ToList()" in your return statement. columnData is already a List type. Try changing your return statement to:

```
return columnData.ToArray<string>();
```